# varnish 4 - abandon, vcl_synth, and restarting requests with new headers

Tags: varnish

I've already asked and received an awesome answer about how to get an error from the backend to force serving from stale cache (grace) found here: [varnish 4: serve graced object if beresp.status is an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33489984/5518061)

but now that logic needs an extra step: i include the following code currently

```
sub vcl_backend_fetch {
  if (bereq.retries == 0) {
    unset bereq.http.X-Varnish-Backend-5xx;
    unset bereq.http.X-Varnish-Backend-206;
  } else {
    if (bereq.http.X-Varnish-Backend-5xx) {
      return (abandon);
    }
    if (bereq.http.X-Varnish-Backend-206) {
      return (abandon);
    }
  }
}

sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 503 &&
    req.method != "POST" &&
    !req.http.X-Varnish-Restarted-5xx) {
    set req.http.X-Varnish-Restarted-5xx = "1";
    return (restart);
  }

  if (resp.status == 503 &&
    req.method != "POST" &&
    !req.http.X-Varnish-Restarted-206) {
    set req.http.X-Varnish-Restarted-206 = "1";
    return (restart);
  }

}
```

obviously the second if statement in the vcl_synth is virtually identical to the first one, with the exception of the header it's looking for. I need to differentiate the 206 to restart with a different request header, but I am not sure how. the issue is that, if the backend returns a 206, the rest of the logic abandons the backend fetch (which hands off to vcl_synth with a 503), and vcl_synth restarts the request to force serving graced cached objects. however, if there's no graced cache object to return to the user, then the user sees a 503 instead of a 206.

Before realizing that this line of thinking was not possible, i tried to have vcl_backend_fetch return a synth(206), so that vcl_synth could use resp.status to differentiate, and add a different request header before restarting the request. then i would be able to look for that header in vcl_miss, and if it's there, i could restart the whole request a second time, and force it to serve the 206 from the usual backend.

TL;DR: how do I differentiate two different cases in a vcl_backend_fetch abandon, to get vcl_synth to restart the request with two different headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to do anything in `vcl_backend_fetch` in order to abandon the request and transfer some kind of flag to `vcl_synth`.

I'm not sure if I've completely understood your use case, but it seems that would need something like:

```
sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 503 &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        !req.http.X-Varnish-Restarted-5xx) {
        # Let's restart the request for the first time and try to 
        # serve grace content. This could select an always-sick
        # backend during vcl_recv.
        set req.http.X-Varnish-Restarted-5xx = "1";
        return (restart);
    }

    if (resp.status == 503 &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.http.X-Varnish-Restarted-5xx &&
        !req.http.X-Varnish-Restarted-206) {
        # Grace content was not available after the first restart. Let's 
        # restart again the request and try to serve content using some
        # other backend.
        set req.http.X-Varnish-Restarted-206 = "1";
        return (restart);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, i think you're right, i can't do specifically what i want, but i can have vcl_synth look for a collection of headers that will build up after restarts.